# Getting "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body" when calling withContext(Dispatchers.Main) inside a lambda

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating a coroutine using the script below:

```
fun bar(completion: () -> Unit) {
  GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val lambda = {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { //Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body
        completion()
      }
    }
    foo(lambda)
  }
}

fun foo(lambda: () -> Unit) {
  //...do something heavy
  lambda()
}
```

But I am getting the error `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` when I call `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` because the lambda changes the context. I cannot change `foo(lambda: () -> Unit)` to `foo(lambda: suspend () -> Unit)` because it's from an external library.

Any idea of what I can do to call `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` inside the lambda created inside the `launch` context?

- Kotlin version: 1.3.41
- Coroutines: 1.3.0-RC

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can rewrite your `bar` function like this:

```
fun bar(completion: () -> Unit) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suspendCoroutine<Unit> {
            val lambda = {
                it.resume(Unit)
            }
            foo(lambda)
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the explanation of this solution?

Comment: this answer is pretty useless without an explanation

Comment: Fantastic, this worked great!
Explanation-wise the coroutine has to manually suspended and the resumed from the callback, since the callback is not coroutine-aware. This way you signal that you are ready to continue the coroutine from a non-coroutine code block (ie: the callback)

Comment: More reading here https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/suspendcoroutine

Answer (score 0):

```
fun bar(completion: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val lambda : suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit =  {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { //Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body
                completion()
            }
        }
        foo(this,lambda)
    }
}

private suspend fun foo( coroutineScope: CoroutineScope , lambda : suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit)  {
    lambda.invoke(coroutineScope)
}
```

also like this

```
fun bar(completion: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        foo(this){
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { //Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun foo( coroutineScope: CoroutineScope , lambda : suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit)  {
    lambda.invoke(coroutineScope)
}
```

Comment: please mention what is the logic behind your code

Comment: Here's an explanation: Kotlin is the new Perl.